# How to style a row in a table?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm having a little issue styling a row in my table. Basically My table has 4 rows.

a) If the value under column **Title 5** is less than 0 then the whole **row needs to be in red color**

b) If the value under column **Title 5** is equal to 17 than the whole **row needs to be in orange color**.

c) Any other row **should NOT** have any color.

I have most of it working. **My issue is:**

> If a row doesn't have any color I still want to make the **check icon
>   green**.

Here's my working code:

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/YnAYeWMiOCKpW6xGvkRG?p=preview)

```
<p-panel  class="a-panel-checkIn" header='Compliance Tracking' [toggleable]="true" [collapsed]="isPanelCollapsed" [style]="{ height: '100%' }">
  <p-table [value]="complianceTracking" [columns]="cols" selectionMode="single">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
      {{col.header}}
    </th>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
  <tr [ngClass]="rowData.field5 < 0 ? 'a-danger-row' : (rowData.field5 === 17) ? 'a-yellow-row' : 'a-green-row'">
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngClass]="rowData[col.field] === '' ? 'a-check-icon' : ''">
      {{rowData[col.field]}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</p-panel>
```

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the green color from the tex, but i want to keep the green color on the check icon. Any ideas how to make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the following code for your second `ng-template` in your `app.template.html`:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
  <tr [ngClass]="rowData.field5 < 0 ? 'a-danger-row' : (rowData.field5 === 17) ? 'a-yellow-row' : ''">
    <!-- <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngClass]="rowData[col.field] === '' ? 'a-check-icon' : ''"> -->
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngClass]="rowData[col.field] === '' ? ((rowData.field5 > 0 && rowData.field5 !== 17) ? 'a-check-icon a-green-check' : 'a-check-icon' ) : ''">
      {{rowData[col.field]}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

In your `styles.css`, create a new css rule as following:

```
.a-green-check {
   color: #A8CF45;
}
```

Here is the [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BlU8qwYagBXZ9sAVDn7H?p=preview)

Hope this is what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 1):

Update your template as below:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
  <tr [ngClass]="rowData.field5 < 0 ? 'a-danger-row' : (rowData.field5 === 17) ? 'a-yellow-row' : ''">
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngClass]="rowData[col.field] === '' ? 'a-check-icon' : ''" class="{{col.field=='field6' && rowData.field5!==17 && rowData.field5>0  ? 'a-green-row':''}}">
      {{rowData[col.field]}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Output:

[image]